# Same preferences for all users in Acrobat Reader?

Tags: remote-desktop, adobe-reader, roaming-profiles, terminal-server

On a W2k8R2 server we have an installation of Acrobat Reader 11. It's necessary to set specific preferences (in Reader prefs) for trusted paths and signing documents.

Different users do connect to the server by rdp. Unfortunately all users to have their own preferences.

Instead of setting preferences for 200+ users individually (when they're logged in), I'd like to to have "global preferences".

I want to set preferences as they have to be and all users have these preferences I specified.

Is there a way to have something like "global preferences" for all users in Acrobat Reader on one machine?

Thanks in advance,
jac

Answer (score 0):

The settings of Acrobat Reader should appear in the registry

Once You have configured it on a PC, just go to the registry:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\>PRODUCT<\>VERSION<\AVGeneral`
and export the settings, than try running the reg file on another PC.

I have not tried this yet, it is just theoretical, so before You do this, make a backup of the current registry settings first.
Give me feedback of the results so in case I can do some more research.